# Display an array in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, drop-down-menu, handsontable

I want to display a php array in a js dropdown. My problem is in this picture :

[image]

I don't get each element of my array but an array of "object" and I don't understand why.

So, I make the array from a sql request, and I get all the data.

```
            $conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
            $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

            $sql = "SELECT ".$colonne." FROM public.".$tablevar."";
            $res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");

            //print_r($sql);
            $data = pg_fetch_all($res);
```

And I'm tryning to display this array in a dropdown like that :

```
type:'dropdown',
source:<?php echo json_encode($arrayData);?>
```

So I don't understand why I don't get the data in the dropdown. Can someone help me please ?

Comment: You've got an array of objects not an array of strings. make console.log() of your var which consist '<?php echo json_encode($arrayData);?>'

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the value inside the object. Try to do a:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayData);
echo "</pre>";
```

And try to see what's inside to get what you want.